# Xamarin Studio community treats handled exception as unhandled exception

Tags: xamarin, parse-platform, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have this problem where I get unhandled exception crash on my Xamarin Android app. I'm trying to login user into [parse.com](http://parseplatform.org/) using user session token. The statements are put inside try-catch block to catch exceptions. But catch block fails to catch "Invalid session token" error from parse.com and app crashes. Catch block works fine if I manually tamper sessionToken.

Here's what I am doing

```
try {
   await ParseUser.BecomeAsync(sessionToken);
   ...
} catch (Exception e){
//log exception
}
```

when there is invalid session token error, above code crashes saying "unhandled exception...." even though it was put inside try block.

following code works. (manually tampering token)

```
try {
   await ParseUser.BecomeAsync(sessionToken + "test");
   ...
} catch (Exception e){
//log exception
}
```

Parse component from [Xamarin Component store](https://components.xamarin.com/view/parse)

What am I missing?

Also, same code works just fine with Xamarin.iOS.

**EDIT** Adding StackTrace

```
  at Parse.Internal.ParseCommandRunner+<>c__DisplayClass2.<RunCommandAsync>b__1 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x000eb] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1`2[TIn,TResult].<OnSuccess>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x0006f] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00033] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00033] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Hyphen_App.Droid.SplashActivity+<setCurrentUser>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00035] in /Chethan Shetty/GIT/android-parent/Hyphen_App.Droid/Splash/SplashActivity.cs:112
```

**EDIT 1** After changing setCurrentUser to following, I am able to catch the exception but after 3-4 seconds app crashes by itself giving " System.AggregateException"

```
 void setCurrentUser(string sessionToken,Action<bool> callback){
       try {
             ParseUser.BecomeAsync(sessionToken).Wait();
             callback(true);
       }catch(AggregateException e){
             e.Handle( x => { return true; });
             callback(false);
       }
```

Comment: are you sure the omitted code is not relevant? could you include the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @woelliJ added stacktrace.

Comment: how are you calling your method `setCurrentUser` ?

Comment: calling from onCreate() of SplashActivity.cs

Comment: are you awaiting it? sometimes it's not properly called when you don't await the task

Comment: I'm not awaiting setCurrentUser() but there is a callback() function does the samething for me. callback() is called after awaiting ParseUser.BecomeAsync()

Comment: try awaiting it

Answer (score 0):

Like you said in the comments you were calling the `async` method in your `OnCreate` without `await`ing it.

It can cause the Exception not to be caught, if the somewhere in the async stack a task is not awaited.

I hope it helped you resolve the issue.

---

### Update

Sorry for not expressing me clearly. Your code must look something like that:

```
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        await this.SetCurrentUser();
    }

    private async Task<bool> SetCurrentUser(string sessionToken)
    {
        try {
            await ParseUser.BecomeAsync(sessionToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

to use the `await` keyword was what i was referring to when saying 'awaiting'.

With the async / await keywords in C#, callbacks are rarely used in asynchronous scenarios anymore. There is a short introduction over at [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Comment: able to catch the exception but after 3-4 seconds I get this ( https://ibb.co/g1FByQ ) error and app crashes.!

Comment: Can you update your question with the stacktrace of that exception? Can't really see much in that screenshot

Comment: (btw. i'd suggest you eventually switch to VS Community, since Xamarin Studio is no longer under active development)